# How to bulk delete unattached images in WordPress using WP CLI and exclude specific authors?

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

Task is to delete all images within a month's archive that are not assigned to a post and have not been uploaded by the admin (user_id 1). The number of affected images is large (>50.000 images), so they have to be deleted image by image.

Command: Delete unattached images line by line and exclude the admin:

```
for id in $(wp db query "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_date>='2020-11-01' AND post_date<='2020-11-30' AND post_type='attachment' AND post_parent=0 AND post_author !='1'" --silent --skip-column-names)
do
    wp post delete --force $id
done
```

Is the solution

Comment: how can `-1` match as post author?

Comment: In wp query -1 gives all posts except post from author with id 1 . I had also tried AND NOT post_author='1'

Comment: Found the solution and updated the command